# Amazon Products Advertising API doesn't return images

Tags: api, web-services, amazon-advertising-api

It mostly works fine, but for some products it doesn't return an image at all even though there are some on Amazon website.

Here's an example of the product I'm having a problem with: http://amazon.it/dp/B004X4VOSQ

As you can see, it has 5 images, but I can retrieve none from their API.

I'm using the following request: `http://webservices.amazon.it/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&AssociateTag=xxxx&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B004X4VOSQ&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CMedium&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-01-12T11%3A40%3A12Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

And getting the following response (with the sensitive data removed): http://pastebin.com/fudLZZTB

There are no `ImageSets` or `MediumImage` groups or anything of the sorts. As I said, the problem only happens with some products. Others work just fine.

For example:

URL: http://www.amazon.it/dp/B000CRBEJ2

Request: `http://webservices.amazon.it/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&AssociateTag=xxxxx&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B000CRBEJ2&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CMedium&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-01-12T11%3A32%3A05Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Response: http://pastebin.com/jASjscQ4

It contains `SmallImage`, `LargeImage`, `MediumImage` and `ImageSets` groups, but request is pretty much identical to the previous one, except for `ItemId` and `Signature`. Any ideas why it happens? Am I making some kind of mistake while forming a request? Is it just a bug of Amazon? How can I make it to retrieve an image?

Answer (score -1):

I just ran a query with the Scratchpad for this item you referenced:

http://www.amazon.it/dp/B004X4VOSQ

And I received the images in the XML response similar to the second example you gave.

Did you retry the request?